# Setting Database Context in a Stored Procedure in Teradata

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, teradata

I'm developing a stored procedure in Teradata, and I want to set the database context inside it, so the entire procedure operates within a specific database. Outside of the stored procedure, I can easily achieve this using the `DATABASE` command, as shown below:

```sql
-- Select table with database context
DATABASE RandomDatabaseName
SELECT * from RandomTableName
```

However, when I try to use the `DATABASE` command inside the stored procedure, it doesn't work as expected:

```sql
-- Select table with database context inside stored procedure
REPLACE PROCEDURE RandomProcedureName ()
    BEGIN
        DATABASE RandonDatabaseName
        SELECT * FROM RandomTableName
    END;
```

Unfortunately, it seems that the `DATABASE` command is not supported inside a stored procedure. I am aware that I can use dynamic SQL and declare the database name as a variable, but I would prefer an alternative approach if possible.

Is there a way to set the database context inside a stored procedure without using dynamic SQL and without the need to declare the database name as a variable?